# Magento 2 - How to Create Product custom options using patch data

Tags: magento2, product, custom-options

In Magento 2.4, How to Create Product custom options using patch data?

I tried the solution [like this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/353833/35778). But it is giving error as `Area not set`. I tried to set area using DI as values admin, admimhtml, frontend, global, but nothing worked.

Please help me to solve this.